# Is it wise to pay off some of my mortgage early in this case?

Tags: mortgage, financial-advisor, netherlands

I live in the Netherlands. I bought a house a couple of years ago, So far I paid around 30% back, from which 70% are extra payment, as my bank allows me to pay some amount extra yearly fee-free.

I can do extra payment now, but I'm hesitating. I'm putting all my money in the house. I'm thinking maybe it's wiser if I invest. The probably is that I'm a newbie to investment, and really have no experience.

I could think of two options:

- Stock market, but it's pretty bad at the moment. I read about it, and I understand that if I invest now, in 5 years, I might get double money. That sounds a good idea for those who have a lot of money.
- Buying a second home, but that is also a difficult option, because new Dutch law sets prices very high for second homes.

### Any advice on this?

Update, my current interest rate is 1.5% fixed for 5 years, and in 2028 I have to pay whatever the interest value then for another 20 years.

Comment: @DJClayworth 1.5% is considered low in the current economy. But in 5 years, I might need to pay 4%, and thus, the more I repay now, the less this 4$ will be applied to.

Comment: Whatever decision you make now, you can change your mind in 2028. Please edit the interest rate into the question.

Comment: @DJClayworth, question is updated. But how can I change my mind later? I'm asking if it is wise to pay some money back now, or if It is better to invest (second house, stocks ... )

Comment: Sorry I meant "If you don't pay off your mortgage now you can always chose to do so later". Obviously you can't "unpay-off" a mortgage. But then you could probably take an extra loan against the house if you needed extra money in five years.

Comment: @DJClayworth that's not necessary true, because every year I can pay back some money back without any fee, so if I don't do it this year, next year I can only pay the same amount back, while if I decide on a strategy to keep paying back year, next year I would've paid back twice the limit. (Let me know if the idea is not clear, because this is an important part)

Comment: Are you saying that you can pay off N Euros this year, and then another M next year, but if you don't pay off the N Euros this year then you can still only pay off M next year?

Comment: @DJClayworth almost, I'm saying that I can pay back "N" amount every year. The amount is fixed, and it is equal to 10% of my initial mortgage value.

Comment: When the interest rate goes up in 2028, are you then allowed to take out an entirely new mortgage and pay off the old one?

Comment: @DJClayworth what difference would that make? if I pay the remaining amount with a higher interest, or take a new mortage with a new interests which is also high.

Comment: @DJClayworth if you question is about taking a new mortgage from a new bank and thus different intersts in 2028, the answer is year, I can, but that is not very helpful because the interest is high in all banks here in NL, currently it is 4.5%

Comment: If you had 100,000 Euros saved in 2028 and a 200,000 mortgage you could take a new mortgage for only 100,000 and pay off the old mortgage. Effectively reducing your mortgage by 100,000.

Comment: @DJClayworth I can't pay 100k in on go, I can pay back 25k yearly, that is the max.

Comment: @DJClayworth Oh I might got what you mean. So it is like taking a completely new mortgage in 2028, thus it wouldn't matter if I pay now or wait until 2028. that is a clever idea. Though pycologically difficult, to keep the money in my bank all these years.

Comment: Well, you would not keep it in the bank, you would invest it in something that made more money than 1.5%.

Answer (score 3):

You *might* double your money in 5 years of stock market investment.  Or maybe lose half, or break even.

Paying your mortgage early, though, is a *guaranteed* return on investment.

Before deciding to pay extra on the loan, or would ask myself:

1. Do I have an adequate emergency fund?
2. What are fixed deposits paying in my country?
3. How old am I?
4. What is my risk tolerance?
5. What do I see in the economy’s future?
6. How/where in “the stock market” would I put the money?

Comment: That's right, stock market might break me too.
1- Yes. I have enough even if I couldn't work for 6 months
2. I didn't get the question, but I'm allowed to pay some amount back fee-free. 
3- 40
4- Not much, maybe around 10k
5- I don't know
6- I have no experience in stocks

Comment: Q2 asks about “fixed deposit” instruments.  The US equivalent is the CD (Certificate of Deposit).

Comment: are you talking about this? https://www.abnamro.nl/en/personal/savings/savings-deposit/index.html

Comment: @user2226785 exactly what I’m referring to.  And their rates are shockingly low.

Comment: @user2226785 with the interest rates being what they are in Europe, and you being risk averse, the best answer I can give you is, “do what makes you sleep best at night."

Comment: @user2226785 note also that you can always stop paying extra later on…

Comment: Focusing on your #2 - If my loan is sub 2%, and I can invest safely, i.e. CDs or similar, at 5%, it seems that would be the wise choice. It helps with liquidity and gains me a few % each year. But, your "do what helps you sleep at night" is the best financial advice one can give.

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica "If my loan is sub 2%, and I can invest safely, i.e. CDs or similar, at 5%, it seems that would be the wise choice."  Loan payments due every month, while the bulk of the CD is freed when it matures.  Now, it would be great if you could get a 2% loan where the whole chunk is payable at the end, but those aren't too common.

Comment: I see the OP posted what return he’d get in his country. My comment was US-centric, I’d admit. In the US, I don’t believe pre-payments are limited as in his country. CDs typical penalty is 3 mo interest to cash out early. In the US, my comment stands. A 1yr CD is far less liquid than the cash tied up by pre-paying one’s mortgage.

Answer (score 3):

You say your mortgage rate is 1.5% for the next five years. In the current climate that's incredibly low. There are some savings accounts that pay higher interest rates than that. You are likely to be able to find safe and secure investments that will pay better than that. If that's the case then you should not pay off your mortgage, but instead invest the money.

Investing in the stock market is risky. You might make a ton of money, but you might lose some as well. If you are OK with the idea of perhaps losing money then go ahead. But if you are not there are plenty of alternatives.

The safest are Fixed Income investments, where you give a bank your money and they pay you a fixed interest rate and then give you back the money at the end. The interest rates are usually higher than a savings accounts, but not by much.

The next best is what we in Canada call a Mutual Fund, and I believe is called a SICAV in the Netherlands. They come with various degrees of risk, and if you pick a conservative one you are very unlikely to lose money. Average rates of return are significantly better than Fixed Income.

However the best advice is to **consult an investment professional** about where you might put your money. They can advise on likely rates of return and degrees of risk. They can also advise about tax implications. These are important to your decision because you will pay tax on any investments you make, but paying off your mortgage is essentially "tax free" - you don't get taxed on mortgage payments you are not making.

The other thing to think about is what else you might need the money for. If you might have a big expense coming up (getting married, getting more education, buying a yacht) then keep some money where you can withdraw it at the right time. Also make sure you've got a little bit money easily accessible in case of an unexpected expense.

In my unprofessional opinion you are going to easily be able to find a safe, secure investment that returns better than 1.5%, and so you probably should not pay off your mortgage.

Comment: `There are some savings accounts that pay higher interest rates than that` we have negative interests on Savings here in NL.  ` They can also advise about tax implications` there are no tax implications about paying a specific amount back yearly, I've done it before. `Fixed Income` is a good idea, though new to me, I shall read more about it.  `In my unprofessional opinion you are going to easily be able to find a safe, secure investment that returns better than 1.5%` I'm not sure about this, so far I've reduced my monthly payment by 400 euros, and that will be fore 8 years = 38k euros

Comment: Here's the link I used for savings rates: https://thebanks.eu/compare-banking-products/savings-accounts/Netherlands My opinion is entirely unprofessional. My strongest advice is to talk to a professional investor, work out if you could make more money by investing, and then make your decision based on that.

Comment: Would the downvoter like to explain?

Answer (score 2):

Not trying to give the best advice, but make you some money: Your mortgage is 1.5% per year. Look for a savings account with a reputable bank, you should be able to get much higher interest rate. Put the money you wanted to pay off into that savings account. 
You make some money, not much, but it is safe. Take the longest terms. If you paid your mortgage off, there would be no way to access the money, do you can have an account fixed for two or five years. Whatever pays the highest interest.

Correction: I found a site showing savings rates in the Netherlands. Oh f***. In the uk, 4% from a high street bank is no problem (right now).

Answer (score 1):

I am in a very similar situation. I didn't know anything about investing until recently and still don't know much about it, so take this with a grain of salt, but because the situation is so similar I thought I'd let you know what we did.

Like you we bought a house a couple of years back. Our mortgage has a 1.2% interest rate fixed for the next 8 years. We never have a fee for paying off early, no matter the amount. Because of an inheritance we were deciding between paying off early, saving, and investing.

- Given that the mortgage interest can be deducted before taxes (*hypotheekrenteaftrek*), the mortgage only costs us about 0.8%. At the moment there are saving accounts with a higher rate, so there is no point in paying off the mortgage right now.

  - If there is a chance you will move to another house it may be better not to pay off the mortgage as well. Interest rates will likely increase, and it is possible to take your mortgage to your next house with the same rate (*oversluiten*). So in this case you want your mortgage to be high, so that you need to borrow less for the increased rate.
  - If there is a limit to the amount you can pay off early without a fee, it may still be wise to do so, depending on what you expect the interest to be when it becomes variable.
- The >0.8% saving accounts are not green and sustainable products, and we wanted to limit ourselves to that. Then there are longer term deposit accounts (*depositospaarrekening*) which can get you around 2%, but you have to pay a fee if you want to withdraw early. A five year deposit might be an option, so that you can withdraw around the same time as the interest on the mortgage becomes variable.
- We then looked at investment options. The [VEB has nice information for beginning investors](https://www.veb.net/beginnen-met-beleggen). We again limited ourselves to green and sustainable products (*artikel 8 and 9*), so if you do not care about this you can get a better return on investment. This is what we eventually went with: a low-risk, low-yield defensive mix fund, together with MFIs (*microkrediet*). But we only chose this because:

  - We have a buffer and earn slightly more than we spend, so we don't end up in problems if we lose this money.
  - The defensive strategy of the fund means that even with a short horizon (8 years, or less if we move to a larger house before then) there is a reasonable chance that bad years can be compensated for. In general, the more risk you take, the longer a horizon you need. The funds we considered had a minimum advised horizon of 5 years, we did not see funds with a shorter advised horizon (the ASN Bank has funds with an advised horizon of 3 years on the website, but in the essential information document it then says 5 years).
  - We added MFIs to the portfolio because they are relatively stable against the backdrop of the war in Ukraine. Otherwise, the mix fund managers ensure spreading.
  - We spread our investment over time: investing part of our money every week for a total of 9 months. This is safer because you don't have the risk of starting on a peak. It also allows us to get a feeling whether we are comfortable with the whole investment thing without going all-in immediately.
- I cannot weigh in on the second home option because we did not have enough money for this to consider it. Though based on common sense I would want to buy a second home at a moment house prices are low, while the market is cooling off only very slowly. Letting that house can be a source of easy income though, but can also give a lot of extra work (laws are very much in favour of the renter in the Netherlands).

> Stock market, but it's pretty bad at the moment. I read about it, and I understand that if I invest now, in 5 years, I might get double money.

In sustainable funds, this return on investment is only forecast for aggressive funds in good scenarios. Again, non-sustainable funds will be able to get higher yields, and I cannot speak to that. But for the sustainable funds, the average case would yield around 25% for aggressive funds, or 100-150% in "good" forecasts (a 2.5% chance that it will be even better). But again, high possible yields go hand in hand with higher risks, and therefore need a longer horizon (see above).